# Washing machine installation - unsure about current setup

Tags: plumbing, faucet, washing-machine

Just moved into a new home and ordered a washing machine from Currys (I am UK based), I have booked installation with the delivery, but just want to make sure I have everything required before installation - Especially in regards to the hot/cold taps that seem to be missing!

I have attached a few photos that show where the previous owners had their washing machine installed - **will the Currys guys need anything else for installation or are we all good?** Besides the waste pipe, I can't make any sense of this setup (previously lived in a flat where the hot/cold taps were clearly labeled).

I assume C is for cold and H is for hot, but where are the actually taps? Where does the water supply come from? What is with that piece labelled "A.F.L W 3/4"?

[image]
[image]

New image:
[image]

Comment: Well, you definitely need to clean the cheap texture job they flung on the walls out of the fittings, for a start. If there is a picture of "AFLW 3/4" it seems to have gotten lost in the upload.

Comment: Those large "nuts" look like caps for 3/4" pipe  that should have spigots on them.  the two smaller "holes" in the wall appear to be the shut off valves for the pipes.  Try removing those caps and experiment  so you'll know what's what.

Comment: @JACK spot on, unscrewing the Cold cap was easy, turning on the valve with a slotted screwdriver got the water running (bucket came in handy!), I assume the washing machine can just screw on to this tap? See image: https://i.imgur.com/f1YIMHk.png

Comment: @joao  It would sure seem so, you do have shutoff valves but I'm not sure about any code requirements. You should  contact the installers or check your  purchase info to see if what they need is stated.

Comment: @joao  Did you get the new one installed???

Comment: Hey, they are coming in to do it later on the month, will update with what they say and do!

Comment: @JACK So just as an update... I'm glad I came in here and asked about this! The moment the Curry's guys came in and had a look, they said "can't do it mate, no cold water supply!"... Don't think they had ever seen something like this! Anyway, I got it to work fine, washing machine is now connected and working as required. Once I explained the setup to them, they still said "you'll have to turn the valve on yourself, we can't be responsible for what happens!" , fair enough mate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those large "nuts" look like caps for 3/4" pipe that should have spigots on them. the two smaller "holes" in the wall appear to be the shut off valves for the pipes. Try removing those caps and experiment so you'll know what's what.

Answer (score 0):

You need to supply some taps and check thsat the water supply is working.

From what you show, it all seems to have been capped off during the re-plastering or painting.

The installers will be prepared to connect to existing taps but **not** supply and fit taps etc

The waste I would expect to be a bit higher but that also depends on the machine instructions.

I assume the electrical supply is close.

Comment: See original post, I added a new image - managed to unscrew the Cold cap and expose the tap, I assume the washing machine can just screw on to this tap? (turning on the valve underneath with a slotted screwdriver turns on the water supply - lucky to have a bucket next in hand :) )